# Simple Way to Convert an Adjacency Matrix to a CSR Graph and Vice Versa

Tags: algorithms, graphs, weighted-graphs, adjacency-matrix

Let's say for the following weighted, undirected graph:

[image]

I am given the adjacency matrix `A[5][5]`:

```
[0][3][4][0][0]
[3][2][0][0][0]
[4][0][0][6][5]
[0][0][6][0][1]
[0][0][5][1][0]
```

What is a simple algorithm to convert the adjacency matrix `A` to a CSR (compressed sparse row) graph in the format of three lists:

```
row_ptr[]
col_ind[]
val[]
```

And how about the other way around? (ie CSR to adjacency matrix)

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12969842/converting-edgelist-to-compressed-sparse-row-in-c)

---

### Edit:

Here's the CSR representation of the graph above: (and some explanation)
[image]

Note that each value `val[i]` in the adjacency matrix is at the `(x,y)` coordinate`(col_ind[i],`index of `row_ptr` where `row_ptr[index]` equals `i+1)`of the adjacency matrix.

Additionally, the last element of `row_ptr` is equal to the number of edges+1.

Comment: Please add an explanation of CSR. Also, what is wrong with the answers to the stackoverflow question? Finally, this sounds like a programming question. Is there a non-trivial algorithm or data structure hiding here, which is required for implementing the conversion?

Comment: Are you saying I should migrate this question to Stack Overflow?... also here's a CSR explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix